# How to get Current Transaction Id in SQL Azure

Tags: transactions, azure-sql-database

In Non-Azure, I can get the current transaction details by using following query but the support to this view is removed from SQL Azure and I did not find anything similar which can tell me current transaction Id.

select * from sys.dm_tran_current_transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and I was able to solve it using the following SQL statement in my trigger

```
select @TransactionId = transaction_Id from 
sys.dm_tran_session_transactions 
where session_id = @@spid
```

This seems to give me what I was looking for and I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not a more correct way of doing this

```
SELECT CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID()
```

From

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-transaction-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)